# Okta react cannot post error when coming from okta tile

Tags: oauth-2.0, okta, okta-api

I am using the below link https://github.com/okta/samples-js-react/tree/master/okta-hosted-login from GitHub to create an application for okta react. it works fine but when I am trying to access the application from okta tile with the below configuration in okta:

`"Send ID Token directly to app (Okta Simplified)"`

Then I am getting error cannot post in react UI.
The value of Initiate login URI is `http://localhost:3000/implicit/callback`

Answer (score 0):

Send ID Token directly to app (Okta Simplified): When the end-user clicks on the application chiclet at Okta dashboard, Okta mints an id_token and makes a POST request to the 'initiate_login_uri' with the id_token in the body of the POST request.

You could handle POST request in your server and then redirect to a page in your app.